# Drawbacks of using JBoss' generic resource adapter for a third-party JMS provider

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, jca, generic-jms-ra

Some third party JMS providers do not provide a JMS JCA resource adapter for JBoss. In that scenario there is an alternative way to set up a generic JMS resource adapter in lieu of a custom one provided by the provider:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Configure_a_Generic_JMS_Resource_Adapter_for_Use_with_a_Third-party_JMS_Provider.html

What are the implications of this? What are the gains of using a provided resource adapter other than simpler configuration and what do JMS providers look for when creating these?

Answer (score 0):

My experiences:

**NIRVANA**

I configured jms generic resource adapter for JBoss 7.1.1 and Universal Messaging [Nirvana](http://terracotta.org/downloads/universal-messaging), the abstraction is guaranteed and communication works fine. But i've a memory lack issue when the connectivity is absent.
These problems are solved when the broker provides own JCA resource adapter. There are more optimizations in that way.

**WMQ**

For WMQ all works fine and there aren't any issue, using "*wmq-ra.rar*".

Answer (score 0):

For information on configuring the RA inside JBOSS please look at

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031820_.htm